# method returns AppCompatActivity in a Fragment

Tags: java, android, android-library

I am trying to implement an [AlertView library](https://github.com/Hamadakram/AlertView) from GitHub in a fragment and the `show()` method returns `AppCompatActivity` so basically is must be like so : `show(this);` but since I'm in a fragment I cannot do that, I tried :

- getActivity();
- returning a context
- ...etc

but nothing worked.

So my question is how to return `AppCompatActivity` while I'm inside a `fragment`

P.S. I tried to read the documentation but found nothing

Comment: did you try something obvious like  casting `getActivity()` result to  `AppCompatActivity` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
alertView.show((AppCompatActivity)getActivity());
```